# Bootstrap Navbar Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a little problem with my navbar. I want my navbar to be responsive and did well so far. But since I started using a dropdown menu in my navbar and test in on the mobile (smartphone, tablet) view, my dropdown toggler and the dropdown menu itself are somehow at the wrong position.

My navbar is below, let me know if you need anything else from my code.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top ">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= root_path %>">test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "nav-link #{current_page(root_path )}" %>
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Posts", posts_path, class: "nav-link #{current_page(posts_path)}"%>
        </li>
        <div class="btn-group nav-item ">
          <%= link_to "Books", books_path, class: "nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary-no-border"%>
          <button class="nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary-no-border dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <h6 class="dropdown-header">Categories</h6>
            <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
              <li class="dropdown-item <%= 'active' if params[:category] == category.name %>">
                <%= link_to category.name, books_path(category: category.name) %>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
          </div>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Help", help_path, class: "nav-link #{current_page(help_path)}"%>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Contact", contact_path, class: "nav-link #{current_page(contact_path)}"%>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <%= link_to full_name(current_user), current_user, class: "nav-link #{current_page(current_user)}"%>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %>
          <% else %>
          <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, class: 'nav-link'%>
          </li>
          <% end %>
        </li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see below my mobile navbar-dropdown expands but the toggler and its menu itself are totally at the wrong position.

[image: The whole image]

Comment: what do you mean with wrong position? could you share a screenshot or something?

Comment: yes sure, i added a picture.

Comment: Share the full screenshot

Comment: Alright, sorry for that. I added the whole picture now. As you can see, my mobile navbar seems to have a problem with it's position.